# Protocol Buffer: Objective-c writeDelimitedToOutputStream - no ACK from receiver

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, tcp, protocol-buffers

I am using **protocol buffers v3.0.0 - beta 2.0** (syntax = "proto3") to send/receive multi-message data between **iOS objective-c sender** and **win10 java receiver**.

The first message was written successfully and read/parsed successfully. Subsequent messages could not be written though because NSOutputStream's *hasSpaceAvailable* flag kept returning false. The event *NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable* was never triggered either.

I checked the server side. After the first read, inputStream.available() returned 0, the next parseDelimitedFrom() blocked and eventually timed out. *Seems like there is nothing in the receive buffer to be read but yet at the same time the client's send buffer is full.*

Furthermore, soon after, the machine where the server reside hung with memory usage at almost 100% and I had to reboot in order to recover. Was it a network deadlock? What did I do wrong here? Any pointers would be appreciated!

Here are some code:

[Obj-C - Sender]

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)event {
  ...
  case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:

       //do dequeuer msg to send

       [requestMsg writeDelimitedToOutputStream:os];
  ...
}

-(void)writeRequest:RequestMsg *)requestMsg
{

    if ([outputStream hasSpaceAvailable]) {
        [requestMsg writeDelimitedToOutputStream:os];
    } // else queue the msg 
}
```

[Java - receiver]

```
public void receiveAndParse()
  while (true) {
    try {

       RequestMsg requestMsg = RequestMsg.parseDelimitedFrom(inputStream);

       //start a new thread to handle this message

    } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {

        String errmsg = e.getMessage();

        //errmsg is Read timed out after the first successful parseDelimitedFrom

        continue;
    }
  }
}
```

Additional Notes:

1. Not sure if this is relevant. I used Wireshark to observe the packets sent. I noticed that while the receiver kept waiting for something to be read and the sender thought there was no space available for sending, the sender was actually sending a lot of [TCP Retransmission] to the receiver and at some point [TCP Window Full] started to appear.
2. Replacing writeDelimitedToOutputStream/parseDelimitedFrom with a simple [outputStream write: maxLength:] on the sender side and a simple inputStream.read(b,offset,size) on the receiving side works perfectly fine.
3. The java receiver code works fine with a java sender (Android device).